# Jetpack Compose Circle Shape border not being applied as expected

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Given the composable below, I expected to have a dark gray circle with a (white) circular border of 2dp.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(100.dp)
        .border(2.dp, Color.White, CircleShape)
        .clip(CircleShape)
        .background(Color.DarkGray)
)
```

However, this actually leads to the following:

[image: Box with unexpected border]

Is this the expected behaviour? If so, is there a way I can make the border be applied to the outer most edge? I can get the desired effect by setting a content inside `Box` but I was wondering if there was an alternative way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behavior - when cropping is done, some edge pixels become translucent to make the shape look more natural.

So when two identical cropped shapes overlap, those translucent pixels blend in and you see this artifact.

A possible solution is to give a little padding to the inner circle:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(100.dp)
        .border(2.dp, Color.White, CircleShape)
        .padding(1.dp)
        .clip(CircleShape)
        .background(Color.DarkGray)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it did occur to me to play around with the padding, but I kept applying it after the clip. Applying the padding then clipping is a great idea, I wish I had thought of it!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the border on outer edge by overlapping another circle shaped box with having decreased `.size()` with Box as Parent

```kotlin
Box {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(200.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(Color.DarkGray)
    )
    Box(modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.Center)
            .size(180.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(Color.Red)
    )
}
```

Let us wait for the more convenient answer :/